# JavaFX: Maven Plugin - Make the executable file reference to a maven repo instead of the lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

I'm looking for a way to create an executable jar file for my JavaFX application.

I'm currently using the zenjava maven plugin and I use the `jfx:jar` goal. Doing this, all the dependencies are generated on a folder called /lib.

The problem arises when one of the dependencies (a separate project handled by another group) is updated, I would need to rebuild my jar again.

Is it possible to just maybe refer to the dependencies using a pom? (not point to the lib) So I would only update the pom every time a dependency is updated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** nope, not possible

**Long answer:** the JavaFX-Maven-Plugin is usable for development (via `mvn jfx:run`) and deployment (via `mvn jfx:jar` or `mvn jfx:native`).

You are generating a potential deployable package, which already contains everything needed to execute on some targeted machine. You would have to encapsulate your javafx-application with a "pre-loader" which downloads all your required stuff to be executable.

What is the idea behind distributing an application which needs some internet-connection to gather all the required dependencies?

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin.

Comment: Now that you mention it, this just makes perfect sense. I didn't realize until I read your answer. Thanks!